# Outlook 2010 Rules : Move emails CC'ed to someoneelse@email.com to a folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

How do I filter emails CC'ed to someoneelse@email.com and me@email.com to another folder? Outlook only provides "Where my name is in CC", which does not work for my case.

Thanks!

Comment: Outlook has a rule (I'm going by memory here, so please forgive lack of accuracy) which allows you to check the entire message header for certain words. If you add in your two email addresses, this may be "good enough".

Answer (score 2):

Adding names to "with specific words in the recipient's address" does include those who are CC (but also includes those who are in the "To" as well). You didn't specify that you would not want to run the rule if the person is in the To field so let me know if this works or not.

Comment: please post this as comment.